# ReplicaSetNoPrimary error although primary exists

Tags: node.js, mongodb, replicaset

I have recently upgraded my mongodb setup from a standalone to a replica set. It seems as the error is caused by the replica set not having a primary (ReplicaSetNoPrimary), so I checked the replica set status but it seems fine to me (only member is the primary). Note that the connection worked before upgrading to a replica set.

**Connection:**

```
const options = {
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
  serverSelectionTimeoutMS: 30000,
  socketTimeoutMS: 75000,
  keepAlive: true,
};
const client = new MongoClient(
    `mongodb://${username}:${password}@localhost:27017/?authSource=admin&replicaSet=rs0&retryWrites=true`,
    options,
);
await client.connect();
```

**Error:**

```
 /home/script/node_modules/mongodb/lib/sdam/topology.js:325
                 const timeoutError = new error_1.MongoServerSelectionError(`Server selection timed out after ${serverSelectionTimeoutMS} ms`, this.description);
                                      ^
 MongoServerSelectionError: connection <monitor> to 127.0.0.1:27017 timed out
     at Timeout._onTimeout (/home/script/node_modules/mongodb/lib/sdam/topology.js:325:38)
     at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:557:17)
     at processTimers (node:internal/timers:500:7) {
   reason: TopologyDescription {
     type: 'ReplicaSetNoPrimary',
     servers: Map(1) {
       '127.0.0.1:27017' => ServerDescription {
         _hostAddress: HostAddress { isIPv6: false, host: '127.0.0.1', port: 27017 },
         address: '127.0.0.1:27017',
         type: 'Unknown',
         hosts: [],
         passives: [],
         arbiters: [],
         tags: {},
         minWireVersion: 0,
         maxWireVersion: 0,
         roundTripTime: -1,
         lastUpdateTime: 3298259072,
         lastWriteDate: 0,
         topologyVersion: {
           processId: ObjectId { [Symbol(id)]: [Buffer [Uint8Array]] },
           counter: 6
         },
         error: MongoNetworkTimeoutError: connection <monitor> to 127.0.0.1:27017 timed out
             at Connection.handleIssue (/home/script/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connection.js:116:23)
             at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/script/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connection.js:63:41)
             at Socket.emit (node:events:394:28)
             at Socket._onTimeout (node:net:486:8)
             at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:557:17)
             at processTimers (node:internal/timers:500:7) {
           [Symbol(beforeHandshake)]: false
         }
       }
     },
     stale: false,
     compatible: true,
     heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
     localThresholdMS: 15,
     setName: 'rs0',
     maxSetVersion: 1,
     maxElectionId: ObjectId {
       [Symbol(id)]: Buffer(12) [Uint8Array] [
         127, 255, 255, 255, 0,
           0,   0,   0,   0, 0,
           0,   2
       ]
     },
     commonWireVersion: 13,
     logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: undefined
   }
 }
```

**Replica Set Status**

```
rs0 [direct: primary] admin> rs.status().members
[
  {
    _id: 0,
    name: '127.0.0.1:27017',
    health: 1,
    state: 1,
    stateStr: 'PRIMARY',
    uptime: 13174,
    optime: { ts: Timestamp({ t: 1633978566, i: 89 }), t: Long("2") },
    optimeDate: ISODate("2021-10-11T18:56:06.000Z"),
    syncSourceHost: '',
    syncSourceId: -1,
    infoMessage: '',
    electionTime: Timestamp({ t: 1633965396, i: 1 }),
    electionDate: ISODate("2021-10-11T15:16:36.000Z"),
    configVersion: 1,
    configTerm: 2,
    self: true,
    lastHeartbeatMessage: ''
  }
]
```

Comment: try connecting to the `27017` directly via setting `directConnection=true` in connection string (not sure whether `replicaSet` option should present in this case, try both)

Comment: also check that `replicaSet` name is correct

Comment: A replica set with just one member is pointless.

Comment: No they are not: "Change streams are available for replica sets and sharded clusters"
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/changeStreams/

Comment: Transactions are also only available when replicasets are enabled, so for development purposes it makes sense to have only a single member.